# Time fields changing when submitting a form

Tags: infopath

I have a form where users press buttons to get the current time for specific tasks, basically tracking time. The form is a **InfoPath 2010 Web Browser Form** and when I submit from the *preview* in **InfoPath** it is submitting correctly.

When I submit the form from the **SharePoint** that I have it uploaded to the fields that have the different times in them all update the time when I hit the submit button. I cannot figure out why this is happening. Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the default value of the time field properties and make sure there isn't anything wonky in it (I would think it should be empty), since it is only being set on a button click it is behaving abnormally, if you had a now() function on-load I would have you check to see if you have a is blank condition before setting the field value. Is there anything else that might be triggering your button click rule perhaps?